Merge two rasters with the rastercalculator
I like to merge two rasterlayers with the rastercalculator.
The Layer_1 rasterlayer have a rectangularshape with a NoData Area in the center (white area). The uniform value is 10 (green area) and the NoData value is -99.
The Layer_2 is placed in the center of Layer_1. The uniform value is 100 (blue area) and the NoData value is -99 (invisible).
This is the rastercalvculatorcode i use:
("Layer_1@1">0)"Layer_1@1"+("Layer_1@1"<0)"Layer_2@1"
The code didnt work. I always get area of this value -3.4028234663852886e+38 in the middle where layer_2 should be.


Is it possible to merge this two layer with the raster calculator ?

I fill both NoData Values with 0.
AusgaberasterL1 = Layer_1 Value = 10 and 0 for NoData
AusgaberasterL2 = Layer_2 Value = 100 and 0 for NoData
I tried this code for the rastercalculator:
("AusgaberasterL1@1">0) * "AusgaberasterL1@1"+("AusgaberasterL1@1"=0) * ("AusgaberasterL2@1"!=0) * "AusgaberasterL2@1"
I ended up with a weird raster. 
The surrounding value of -3.4028234663852886e+38 are wrong, it should the uniform 10.

Use Fill NoData first on both layers with a "neutral" value (0 if you add afterwards, 1 if you multiply), then combine them.
